# Simplify Raphael JS code: display text in DIV on click event

Tags: javascript, raphael.js

I've been working with the RaphaelJS '[australia map](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html)' example that displays text in a DIV when a state is clicked on. However I'm having difficulty working with it to create different events and functions.

I want to be able to duplicate the 'display text' function for two different element onClick events (i.e. have two different buttons (elements) that do the same thing). But the current code is a bit too complicated for me. Can somebody please help me **simplify the code** that displays the text in a DIV when an element is clicked on.

Any help would be much appreciated - this is what I'm currently working with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSFwc/).

```
 window.onload = function () {
    var R = Raphael("paper", 532, 500);
    var attr = {
        fill: "#0B0",
        stroke: "#fff",
        "stroke-width": 3,
    };
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.btn_1 = R.path("M 180,130 L 340,130, L 392,212, L 128,212 z").attr(attr);
    ctx.btn_2 = R.path("M 128,212 L 392,212, L 435,280, L 85,280 z").attr(attr);

    var current = null;
    for (var state in ctx) {
        (function (st, state) {
            st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
            st[0].onmousedown = function () {
                current && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                st.toFront();
                R.safari();
                document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
                current = state;
            };
        })(ctx[state], state);
    }
 };
```

Comment: That is actually reasonably compact, straightforward code.  Which part were you hoping to simplify, exactly?  One thought: if the click handler is what you're focusing on, you can always declare the function independently and assign it by variable name, rather than reproducing it inline repeatedly.

Comment: The part of code I'm hoping to simplify is the click handler (starting from `var current = null;` to the end of the code). The problem I'm having is trying to rebuild the click handler code - or even calling the function to be used elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkThomas I'll try _codereview_ too, thanks.

Comment: You could user `Paper.set` and make an array of elements. I wouldn't add it to the context as class property. And btw, you can add `'cursor': 'pointer'` to your `attr`. And at last: Don't use `for..in`, because it's very vulnerable, try Google `:)`

Comment: Great, thanks Dan Lee. I'll look into those more. Google to the rescue! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [tiffon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/19471/2634) it's better to extract a function, but I don't agree with the rest of their edits, so here's what I would have done (I also kept the style intact).

```
var initPath = (function () {
    var currentEl;

    function init(el, path) {
        path.attr({
            fill: "#0B0",
            stroke: "#fff",
            "stroke-width": 3,
        });

        path[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
        path[0].onmousedown = function () {
            currentEl && (currentEl.style.display = "");

            path.toFront();
            path.paper.safari();

            el.style.display = "block";
            currentEl = el;
        };
    }

    return init;
})();

window.onload = function () {
    var R = Raphael("paper", 532, 500);
    var paths = {
        'btn_1': R.path("M 180,130 L 340,130, L 392,212, L 128,212 z"),
        'btn_2': R.path("M 128,212 L 392,212, L 435,280, L 85,280 z")
    };

    for (var id in paths) {
        initPath(document.getElementById(id), paths[id]);
    }
};
```

Firstly, I think `st` and `state` were confusing names, so I changed them to be `path` and `id`, respectively, and then changed `id` to `el` to avoid additional lookups.

I separated the infrastructure (`current` and `initPath`) from the usage (`R`, `paths` and the loop).

I also think an object literal looks better than a series of assignments, so I changed that.

Finally, I like it better if I move `initPath` and `currentEl` into a closure of their own—after all, they don't depend on `window.onload` anymore.

I left the inner `init` a named function so it is named in a stack trace, if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shot.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var R = Raphael("paper", 532, 500),
        attrs = {
            fill: "#0B0",
            stroke: "#fff",
            "stroke-width": 3,
            cursor: "pointer"
        },
        paths = [
            {id: 'btn_1', p:"M 180,130 L 340,130, L 392,212, L 128,212 z"},
            {id: 'btn_2', p:"M 128,212 L 392,212, L 435,280, L 85,280 z"}
        ],
        current,
        max,
        i;

    for (i = 0, max = paths.length; i < max; i++) {
        initPath(paths[i].p, attrs, paths[i].id);
    }

    function initPath(pathStr, attrs, targetId) {

        var path = R.path(pathStr).attr(attrs),
            txElm = document.getElementById(targetId);

        path.click(function (e) {
             if (current) {
                 if (current === txElm) {
                     return;
                 }
                 current.style.display = '';
             }
             current = txElm;
             current.style.display = 'block';
             this.toFront();
             R.safari();
        });
     }
 }​
```

Integrated [Dan Lee's comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/simplify-raphael-js-code-display-text-in-div-on-click-event/19471#comment25177_15521) and defined a function instead of making a new closure in each loop iteration.

Comment: I see absolutely no problem with using `for... in` to enumerate object properties, Google did not help. The original `click` logic was idiomatic JavaScript, not sure why you changed it. Also, OP doesn't use jQuery (`[0]` comes from Raphaël).